# Piped Matrix input with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, input

I'm about to receive input for my python script in using the pipe. The first two elements are the numbers of columns and rows in the matrix, followed by the elements of the matrix.

```
cat input | python3 matrix.py
```

The problem is that the file may contain one matrix element in one line or the entire matrix row in one line.

Writing a C program for this is simple. The scanf() automatically starts new input as soon as it encounters a white space, be it space or a new line but that's not the case with python.

Consider the following two input files:

> File 1

```
2
2
1 2
3 4
```

> File 2

```
2
2
1
2
3
4
```

and the following input function:

```
def getter():
    col = int(input())
    row = int(input())

    matrix = []
    for i in range(0, row):
        temp = input()
        matrix.append(temp)
```

This function works for File 1 but not for file 2. But, if I change for loop to this:

```
for i in range(0,row):
    temp = []
    for j in range(0,col):
        temp.append(int(input))
    matrix.append(temp)
```

Then this would work for File 2 and not for File 1.

Is there a generic way to write a python3 program to make it work with both the files?